# fastest way to search and delete files inside a directory

Tags: c#

I've got a array of class in which one member is the full path to a file. I need to delete all those files from the directory which is not included in the array. As Usual, I am using the convential compare and delete method. I need to know if there any fast way to accomplish this. 
I heard it can be done using  Linq, but i dont have knowledge on linq.

My class struct is like below.

```
Class ImageDetails
{

public string Title;

public Boolean CanShow;

public String PathToFile;
}
```

I have an array of ImageDetails. The PathToFile contains full path

}

Comment: @RowlandShaw I think the OP wants to delete all of the *other* files in the directory (but not the ones in the array)

Comment: What is wrong with your `convential compare and delete` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Except() to handle this:

```
var filesToDelete = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(yourClass.FilePath)).Except(yourClass.TheArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to compare? If you have the full file name, then

```
File.Delete(fileName);
```

is all you need. The file IO is likely to be the slowest part of this, so I don't think Linq will make much difference to the performance.

If the file may not exist, then check for that first:

```
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Edit: I see you mean that you want to delete the file if it is not in the array. I read your question to mean that the directory is not included in the array.

Still, the actual file deletion is likely to be the slowest part of this.